# Silverlight 5 Dynamic Assembly Bug

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

There seems to be a nice bug in Silverlight 5 that prevents creation of strong named dynamic assemblies. In Silverlight 4 I was able to strong name my dynamic assemblies by explicitly calling SetPublicKey on the AssemblyName (since StrongNameKeyPair is internal in Silverlight).

Since upgrading to Silverlight 5, my dynamic assembly creation code now throws an error that:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: A strong name key pair is required to emit a strong-named dynamic assembly.
```

Even though I'm calling SetPublicKey explicitly.

Any way to work around this bug?

Comment: Well I doubt there will be any fix for that or workaround considering state that SL is in

Comment: Yep....not that one could expect any better from Microsoft. Thanks.

Comment: This is paining me again in portable class libraries.